# How to trigger an event by reseclecting nodes in the shader workspace PYTHON

Tags: python, node-editor, shaders, select

All I need is actually just a script or something that acts as an event through which other operators can be triggered. The event should be triggered when a user selects a new node in the shader workspace, for example, i.e. the selection is changed.
I suspect that a script has to work constantly in the background to capture this event, but what does this script have to look like and how can it run without freezing Blender?

I love seeing your advice and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty hacky but you can run a timer that scans for open Node Editors and checks if the active material or node name has changed from the last time the timer ran. Not sure if there's a better way.

```
import bpy


LastNodeState = None


# Called when active node changes
def notify_node_changed():
    owner, node = LastNodeState
    print(f"node changed! now '{node}' in '{owner}'")


# Gets an open node editor space
def get_node_editor_space():
    if not bpy.context or not bpy.context.screen:
        return None

    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'NODE_EDITOR':
            for space in area.spaces:
                if space.type == 'NODE_EDITOR':
                    return space

    return None


def poll_for_changed_active_node():
    space_data = get_node_editor_space()
    if not space_data or not space_data.node_tree:
        return

    active_node = space_data.node_tree.nodes.active
    if not active_node:
        return

    global LastNodeState
    node_state = (space_data.id.name, active_node.name)
    if node_state == LastNodeState:
        return
    LastNodeState = node_state

    notify_node_changed()


def timer():
    poll_for_changed_active_node()
    return 1.5  # poll every 1.5 seconds


bpy.app.timers.register(timer)
```